# Verify if a portlet has been successfully deployed in Liferay

Tags: continuous-integration, liferay, portlet, liferay-6, continuous-deployment

We are trying to implement a continuous deployment system on our Liferay Production Cluster, and we could not find a clean way of verifying programatically if the portlets have been successfully deployed.

Right now we have a script that among other things, removes the liferay instance from the load balancer, deploys a series of portlets, and then replaces the liferay instance back in the load balancer. What we don't know how to do is to check if the portlets have been successfully deployed, so we can proceed with the deployment on the remaining machines.

We already thought about creating a simple health check page on a per site basis, or a servlet with a simple page, but those require lots of customization, and require maintenance, when new portlets are added.

Has anyone had this problem before ? Does liferay offer some kind of API, that allows a user to verify if portlets are safely deployed ?

Best Regards,

Comment: there's definitely an API as plugins are shown in ControlPanel and all of Liferay's UI functionality typically goes through an API. Can't look it up currently, thus I'm only commenting. Another alternative might be to ask for static resources deployed with every plugin. At least this shows the availability of the web context, though not the portlet in there.

Comment: I don't have any exp. with Liferay, but I think maybe you can use PorletContextListener class to detect you portelt was sucessfully deployed.